# Declaring two references for a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch some records from different table based on some condition. These tables are somehow relational but my query is giving compilation error.

**This query is get course id of two different classes:**

```
select c.id, c1.id
FROM college.student s 
left join college.classroom (p1, p2) on p1.class_id=s.child_id 
                                    and p2.class_id=s.parent_id 
left join college.course (c, c1) on p1.class_id=c.id 
                                 and p2.class_id=c1.id;
```

I want to take p1,p2 both join them like this. Basically having two joining. Basically just wanted to know how to join taking two different references of same table.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What do you intend with `college.classroom (p1, p2)`?  That is not valid MySQL syntax in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If it was a valid syntax why would I ask the question here in the first place? I just want to ask if I could take two references of same table or is there anything to break this types of query.

Lets say I have table A where I have child and parent id.....this child and parent is the id of another table B where I have some column x which is the id of C table....I want to fetch c.id based on both parent and child of table A

Comment: . . And how is someone supposed to figure out what you want from **broken** syntax?  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation are needed.

Comment: Because I wrote above that I want to take two references since that was syntax error therefore the objective is clear what I wanted from beginning and I got the answer below. I am just verifying....Well I know its a little bit ill formed question but I had this much only thought if anyone could see what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.id, c1.id   /* , s.id  */
FROM college.student s 
left join college.classroom p1 on p1.class_id=s.child_id
left join college.classroom p2 on  p2.class_id=s.parent_id 
left join college.course c on p1.class_id=c.id           
left join college.course c1 on p2.class_id=c1.id;
```

PS. Are you sure that you need in LEFT joins? maybe INNER is enough?

---

> Basically just wanted to know how to join taking two different references of same table.

When you need to refer to a table twice you must use two table copies, separate table copy for each separate reference.